# Invalid Identifier with Join but valid columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join Customers with Order_Header on Customer_ID in Oracle SQL Developer and am running into "invalid identifier" error even though the two tables are valid with column existing in both.

```
Select C.customer_name, Order_Header.total_sales, order_detail.quantity, 
C.customer_ID
From Customers C
Join Order_Header Using (Customer_ID);
```

Comment: You have not defined `order_detail` in the `from` clause.

Comment: the "order details" portion was to be with a third join (right now, I am just focusing on the first), but even with that portion removed, the same error exists.

Comment: I figured out my error. I created my tables using double quotes which resulted in Order_header becoming an invalid identifier as it was not referred to using double quotes.

Comment: . . Don't be offended, but I'm voting to close as a simple typographical error.  There is nothing in the question that can help someone else find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the following?

`Select C.* From Customers C`

and

`Select O.* From Order_Header O`

I would guess you might be missing a schema name `select t.* from schema.table`.

Comment: Both of the queries worked, returning the full tables. Regarding a comment above, the "order details" portion was to be with a third join, but even with that portion removed, the same error exists.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments above, you keep saying that

> the "order details" portion was to be with a third join, but even **with that portion removed**, the same error exists.

What is "that portion"? If you meant a *join with the `ORDER_DETAILS` table*, that "portion" should have been added, not removed. Or, you should remove a column that belongs to `ORDER_DETAILS` table which doesn't exist in the `FROM` clause.

It would help if you provided tables' description; I created them myself, using a minimal column set so that a query would work. Have a look.

```
SQL> -- CUSTOMERS: column names taken from your query
SQL> create table customers
  2    (customer_id   number constraint pk_cust primary key,
  3     customer_name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> -- ORDER_HEADER: ORDER_ID must exist in order to join it with ORDER_DETAIL
SQL> create table order_header
  2    (order_id      number constraint pk_oh primary key,
  3     customer_id   number constraint fk_oh_cust references customers (customer_id),
  4     total_sales   number);

Table created.

SQL> -- ORDER_DETAIL: I added ORDER_ID as a reference to ORDER_HEADER
SQL> create table order_detail
  2    (order_id      number constraint fk_od_oh references order_header (order_id),
  3     quantity      number);

Table created.
```

A *full* query which uses all 3 tables would then look like this:

```
SQL> select c.customer_name,
  2         oh.total_sales,
  3         od.quantity,
  4         c.customer_id
  5  from customers c join order_header oh on oh.customer_id = c.customer_id
  6                   join order_detail od on od.order_id = oh.order_id;

no rows selected
```

---

### As of your query:

```
SQL> -- query you wrote, slightly formatted:
SQL> Select C.customer_name,
  2         Order_Header.total_sales,
  3         order_detail.quantity,
  4         C.customer_ID
  5  From Customers C
  6  Join Order_Header Using (Customer_ID);
       C.customer_ID
       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
```

It means that you should remove the "`C.`" in line 4:

```
SQL> Select C.customer_name,
  2         Order_Header.total_sales,
  3         order_detail.quantity,
  4         customer_ID
  5  From Customers C
  6  Join Order_Header Using (Customer_ID);
       order_detail.quantity,
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "ORDER_DETAIL"."QUANTITY": invalid identifier
```

Now you got another error - you're referencing `QUANTITY` column which belongs to `ORDER_DETAIL` you never referenced in the `FROM` clause; so - remove that column from `SELECT`:

```
SQL> Select C.customer_name,
  2         Order_Header.total_sales,
  3         -- order_detail.quantity,
  4         customer_ID
  5  From Customers C
  6  Join Order_Header Using (Customer_ID);

no rows selected
```

Or, add `ORDER_DETAIL` to the `FROM` clause, which returns you to a query I initially posted.

Comment: tried your joins and still get this error.                                                                     
ORA-00904: "OH"."CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Litttlefoot Data types are Customer: Customer_ID varchar(255), Customer_Name Varchar(255) and Order_Header: Order_ID Varchar (255), Customer_ID Varchar (255)

Comment: I believe I showed pretty well how to do it, and how NOT to do it. I suggest you carefully read what I wrote and apply it to your case.

Comment: I figured out my problem as I referenced above. I do appreciate your help.